# Designing a Django REST API to send JSON requests to a smart meter and get JSON responses

Tags: json, django-rest-framework, api-design

I am designing an API to send JSON requests to a smart meter and get JSON responses.

I have been reading django rest framework tutorials but I don't know if django is the recommended technology for this job.

Here is an example of a request that the api would send to the meter:

```
{
    "GETCODE":{
          "uuid":"1e865d9e-8700-470a-b69a-62fea0f57d7e" #uuid example
          "social_id":"11111111"
    }
}
```

Response :

```
{
    "uuid":"1e865d9e-8700-470a-b69a-62fea0f57d7e"
    "DATA":{
        "code":"xxxxxxx"
        "serial_number":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        "address":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is all it does, Django might be a little heavy for the job.

Comment: @bryan60, after getting it working, I am also supposed to add an interface. Do you think Django is not appropriate? Do you have any suggestions on what to use?

Comment: django is fine for all of this, basically any web framework is. You could probably even use like an API gateway proxy with data mappers as a 0 infrastructure solution tbh

Comment: can you share the API you are using to send data back and forth to the smart meter. is it open PAI based on ANSI C12.18 or something else?